# Azure AD Application registration using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-deployment

Created a ARM template to create a AD Application using deployment scripts in ARM via powershell.

Getting this error

**The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'failed'**

Here is the template

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {
        "cliResourceName": "AzAppRegDeploymentScript"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01-preview",
            "name": "[variables('cliResourceName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
            "identity": {
                "type": "UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "/subscriptions/XXXXX-bXXd-4XX5-b&*e-YDTXXYYYYS/resourceGroups/sample/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mientity": {}
                }
            },
            "properties": {
                "azPowerShellVersion": "9.7",
                "timeout": "PT30M",
                "scriptContent": "$app = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName 'app-d'",
                "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
                "retentionInterval": "P1D"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

what's the error here? CLI also failing.
The user managed identity 'mientity' is provided with a **contributor** role. and roles mentioned in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template#configure-the-minimum-permissions

Answer (score 0):

To create an Azure AD application using deployment scripts via ARM template, you can use below scripts which are given in both PowerShell & CLI.

**Using `AzCLI`:**

```bash
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {
        "cliResourceName": "AzAppRegDeploymentScript"
    },
    "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01-preview",
            "name": "[variables('cliResourceName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "AzureCLI",
            "identity": {
                "type": "UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/newui": {}
                }
            },
            "properties": {
                "AzCliVersion": "2.0.80",
                "timeout": "PT30M",
                "scriptContent": "

                appInfo = $(az ad app create--display - name $1--identifier - uris\ "$2\" --reply-urls \"$3\")
                    echo $appInfo

                    ",
                    "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
                    "retentionInterval": "P1D"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

**Using `AzPowershell`:**

*I received the same error as you when I tried with PowerShell in my environment.*

After a workaround on this issue, I found an approach to deploy it by referring to the [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/using-powershell-in-arm-template/ba-p/3277600) by @Thakur Prasad Mishra.

You can create a script in the GitHub content page and add that respective URL in the `"primaryscripturi"` property of the PowerShell deployment script of ARM template as detailed in the above given blog.

For any of the above deployments(**either Powershell or CLI**), you need to provide the below permissions to the user identity.

1. Add the contributor role under subscription level by going to `subscriptions -> Access control -> Add -> Add role assignment -> Privileged administrator roles -> Contributor` and then select a `user identity`.

[image]

2. You must add an ***"Application Administrator"*** role for the user identity by going to `Roles & Administrators` under `Azure Active Directory`.

[image]

I modified your PowerShell deployment code `properties`block as follows:

```bash
  "properties": {
       "azPowerShellVersion": "9.7",
        "timeout": "PT30M",
        "scriptContent": "
         $ScriptPath = '/home/admin/script.ps1'
         $Info = Get-Content -Path $ScriptPath
         ",
         "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
         "retentionInterval": "P1D"
        }
    }]
}
```

**Script.ps1:**

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Force
Import-Module -Name AzureAD
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName 'app-d'
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

**Note:** *I would suggest you use ***Azure CLI*** version to create deployment scripts for an AD application.*

You can also refer [article](https://moimhossain.com/2020/04/03/azure-ad-app-via-arm-template-deployment-scripts/) by @Moim Hossain for more relevant information.

Comment: Thanks @Jahnavi. Is there anyway to add ***Application Administrator role*** to Managed Identity via ARM template itself

Comment: You can add this PowerShell command `New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment` with the managed identity resource 
 inside the `Script.ps1`. Refer [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-assign-app-role-managed-identity-powershell?tabs=azurepowershell) for better understanding. @DAK

Comment: You can also use [`az app role assignment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli#step-4-assign-role) in the above `scriptcontent` block using CLI. @DAK

Comment: Add this to the `script content` block after `New-AzureADApplication`. 
`\nNew-AzureADMSRoleAssignment -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -PrincipalId $app.ObjectId -ResourceId $app.ObjectId -RoleDefinitionId '18a4783c-866b-4cc7-a460-3d5e5662c884'`. @DAK

Comment: it's failing. without Application Administrator role for managed identity, deployment scripts won't work right?

Comment: For your requirement, this role has to be added and I would suggest you add through Portal itself to make this works efficiently. @DAK

Comment: Did you try adding the role through Portal? @DAK

Comment: Through portal i can add. tried that it worked but my requirement is to add it via ARM template

Comment: If you want to use only ARM template, you can pass [`New-AzureADMSRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsroleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0) PowerShell command under `script content` block in main ARM json file or `script.ps1` with the required parameters. @DAK